# Clearing input changes it from controlled to uncontrolled

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, redux

I am trying to make an input that accepts only positive integers. I am also looking for any tips on where to put the validation logic (if there is a better place).
Right now, I am dispatching redux state changes inside `onChange` if the input. And that's where I validate the value.

I have an input:

```js
<input className='form-control' type='number' value={minors} onChange={ev => dispatch(updateMinors({
                value: Number(ev.target.value) > -1 ? Number(ev.target.value) : 0,
                isValid: !isNaN(ev.target.value) && Number.isInteger(ev.target.value),
                wasValidated: true
              }))} style={{ maxWidth: '6rem' }} />
```

this is connected to redux state using a selector:

```js
const minors = useSelector(state => state.minors.value)
```

I have a reducer for the same:

```js
updateMinors: (state, action) => {
  state.minors.value = action.payload.minors
  state.minors.isValid = action.payload.isValid
  state.minors.wasValidated = action.payload.wasValidated
}
```

The initial redux state for the same slice is:

```js
minors: {
  value: 0,
  isValid: false,
  wasValidated: false
}
```

The default view rendered using this code is:

```
  <div class="input-group mb-1">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" style="max-width: 6rem;">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text" style="min-width: 5rem;">minors</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I try to clear the value using backspace, I get the following warning:

```
index.js:1 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type number to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

I know there is another way of doing this and I am trying to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

---

**Update**
There is a typo in the reducer `action.payload.minor`. It should be `action.payload.value`. 
This caused and `undefined` assignment in the value of input. 
That, in turn, changed the input field from `controlled` to `uncontrolled` and hence the warning.
Fixing the typo fixed the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `onChange` to an input, React will consider it as a controlled input and it will expect a state value to be provided, this is what you do in your code with `value={minors}`

But in your reducer, if you change minors to `null` or `undefined`, then React will consider that you are not providing a value and you will get this error message saying that you're changing from controlled to uncontrolled.

The bug comes from your reducer, where you assign `state.minors.value` to `action.payload.minors`, it should be:

```
updateMinors: (state, action) => {
  state.minors.value = action.payload.value
  state.minors.isValid = action.payload.isValid
  state.minors.wasValidated = action.payload.wasValidated
}
```